# Change site path without reloading site

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a site in react in which I have a homepage with a navbar and a section for the content of the page. I would like to implement a function that depending on the position of the client scroll the url of the navigation bar changes. For example, when entering the site "site.com" it shows me an initial information that I can then scroll down and it shows me the section "who we are" but since this section is visible I want to change the url to "site.com/whoweare "without refreshing the site. Do you have any idea how to achieve this through react? how to change the url without the site refreshing

Comment: You can probably do this with `react-router`.

Comment: This isn't something you do with react, react is just handling view logic. You can look at using the `history` api. Alternatively there are packages that handle this like `react-router` as @Code-Apprentice has aptly mentioned